# Can I enter a paragraph into a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I had a question in my exam where I must add a recipe into a text-box. The recipe was multi-line and my text-box as well but I couldn't enter the text into the textbox if a certain recipes radio button was clicked.

I managed to add single words or a small sentence into the text-box but failed to enter the whole recipe.

```
desriptionlbl.text = "The recipe";
```

//where the recipe would have been the whole recipe

Answer (score 0):

`\t` for TAB and `\n` for ENTER, is what you want?

Comment: Ok it worked. When I tested it, all the text that I had to enter was in an word document so I guess I should have just re write it all in.